# Como persistir em uma rota, usando react router com Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, react, react-router, react-router-dom

Tenho um site em react, e gostaria de saber como persistir em uma rota. Por exemplo: Quando eu estou na página perfil e dou um refresh na página, ele me redireciona para dashboard. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu faço pra quando der reload eu consiga permanecer na rota de perfils?

Arquivo Router.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useAuth } from '../contexts/auth';

const RouteWrapper = ({ component, isPrivate, isNotFound, ...props }) => {
  const { signed } = useAuth();

  if (isNotFound) 
    return <Route { ...props } component={ component } />;
  
  if (!signed && isPrivate) 
    return <Redirect to="/" />;

    
  if (signed && !isPrivate) 
    return <Redirect to="dashboard" />;
  
  return <Route { ...props } component={ component } />;
};

RouteWrapper.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.element,
    PropTypes.func
  ])
};

export default RouteWrapper;
```

Arquivo index.js das rotas

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Route from './Route';

import SignIn from "../pages/SignIn";
import Dashboard from "../pages/Dashboard";
import Profiles from "../pages/Profiles";
import NotFound from "../pages/NotFound";

export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} isLogin />
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} isPrivate />
        <Route exact path="/perfils" component={Profiles} isPrivate />

        <Route component={NotFound} isNotFound />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa função `RouteWrapper` possivelmente ta dando conflito. Você mesmo colocou nela que caso o usuário `!signed && isPrivate` ele seja redirecionado para a pasta raiz. Tente comentar essa parte e fazer um `<Switch>` simples no arquivo de rotas para ver se funciona!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver criando arquivos de rotas separados. AuthRoutes e DefaultRoutes, ai valido o signed, e se for true eu renderizo o AuthRoutes caso contrário renderizo o DefaultRoutes, assim eu tenho rotas especificas para ambos os casos :)